# Counting newlines in a file

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to read the number of newlines in a text file. However, my counter is not working. Is it because of the string comparison?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myFile;
    int temp_height = 0;

    myFile.open("Levels.txt");


    while (!myFile.eof())
    {
        getline(myFile,line);

        if (line == "\n") 
            temp_height++;

    }

    cout<<"\n Newlines: "<<temp_height;
    myFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean blank lines?

Comment: besides using eof being bad, in case you want newlines, the comparison is wrong, in case you want empty lines, compare for empty lines.

Comment: Blank lines or all lines? Oh, and for empty lines [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) will return an empty string. It will never add the delimiter (which is newline by default) to the string.

Comment: I wrongly assumed that to look for blank lines I'd need to look for newlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
while (!myFile.eof())
{
    getline(myFile,line);
```

to

```
while (getline(myFile, line))
{
```

This means you are actually reading before you check, and also that you check for other failures. You almost never want to actually check `eof`, it probably doesn't work quite how you expect.

Edit: Ok, you want blank lines. `getline` discards the `'\n'` character, so check for

```
if (line.empty())
```

for a final loop:

```
while (getline(myFile, line))
{
    if (line.empty())
        ++temp_height;
}
```

You can find documentation for [`std::getline` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: I'm trying to count the number of blank lines - i assumed i should be looking for new lines?

Comment: Not wise to assume, look up getline and find out what it really does.

Comment: thanks for the feedback :D it works now - can i ask why we add the ++ in front of temp_height not in front of it?

Comment: @user1816546 In this case it doesn't really matter, but pre-increment is generally more idiomatic (despite the language being called `C++`!). However, `x++` is generally more expensive, as it involves making an extra copy, which for some types, eg iterators over some complicated container, may be expensive.